# How to translate markers into a half circle with minimal line intersection?

Tags: javascript, geometry, computational-geometry, mathematical-optimization, intersection

I have a map and a lot of markers are displayed on it. Sometimes markers are so close to each-other that they overlap. To remedy this, I have implemented a spiderfier library to remedy this situation.

The idea is to group the markers being close-enough upwards on the screen (downwards mathematically) in such a way that they will not intersect each-other.

Markers are displayed as rectangles.

Implementation:

- traverses the markers and markers which intersect each-other are included into a group with the center of ((minX + maxX) / 2, maxY) and the radius is just large-enough to display the markers on the periphery without intersecting each-other
- while there are semi-circles which intersect each-other, we merge them into a larger half-circle
- we sort the markers by a comparator, placing "smaller" markers to the left on the periphery of the circle compared to their "greater" counterparts
- we display the markers on the top-half circle, but we display a line from their modified location to their real location

So far, so good.

Problem: These lines are intersecting each-other too often and we need a comparator function with which the number of marker line intersection is minimalized.

Tries:

1. P1.x <= P2.x => P1 <= P2
2. arctan((P1.y - C.y) / (R * (P1.x - C.x))) <= arctan((P2.y - C.y) / (R * (P2.x - C.x))) => P1 <= P2

I had high hopes tied to the second try, but had to acknowledge that it is not a good idea, since the translation line and the line between the real location and the center of the circle are not necessarily collinear, in fact, their angle can become fairly big if there are many markers having their real location very close to each-other, whilst the half-circle's surface except this sub-region is fairly barren. So, this leads to intersections as well and it is much more complex than the first try. I believe Javascript's [Math.atan](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan) is implemented either with [Taylor series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html) or [Fourier series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html), which involves derivatives in the first case and integral in the second case. Or, there might be a third approach, which is highly complex as well. I would think about optimizations and stuff like that if this second approach would have significantly reduced the number of intersections, but since the improvement is barely observable if at all, I returned to the first approach.

I am thinking about the following approach:

- calculate the locations of the marker slots on the periphery
- try to translate all the markers to their closest possible slot
- find the conflicting groups and solve all conflicts by finding the optimum, which is the translation-set with the smallest total translation

Is this idea leading to a state where spider line intersection number is minimalized and if not, how could I minimalize the number of such intersections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difficult problems, studied for a long time now.
It is sometimes called
[automatic label placement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_label_placement).
The work cited below is typical of what is available in the literature.

---

[image: USmap]

---

> Van Kreveld, Marc, Tycho Strijk, and Alexander Wolff. "Point set labeling with sliding labels." *Proceedings of the fourteenth annual symposium on Computational geometry*. ACM, 1998. [ACM link](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=276922).

Comment: Thank you, Joseph for the description and sources.